# Does anyone know a good pixel font 7px tall?

Tags: fonts, font-face, font-size, pixel, pixel-art

I'm looking for a pixel font which I'll use later on to convert/use on an lcd type of display and the maximum height is 7px.

I've started by checking out [dafont's bitmap fonts](http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php), but it takes quite a while to test all of them. I've played with a few and I'm surprised to see only a few work well when set to a small size (7px max height). I was hoping someone might have had a chance to play with more and recommend them.

In the meantime I've started designing mine, just a few characters for a quick test/demo, but I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel when it's not needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Joe Gillespie did some great micro screen font work under the MiniFonts moniker.
These are still [available via MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/foundry/MiniFonts.com/).

[Silkscreen](http://kottke.org/plus/type/silkscreen/) is a related design by Jason Kottke.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of great pixel fonts at [FontsForFlash.com](http://www.fontsforflash.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can download some good pixel fonts from [FontsBase.com](http://www.fontsbase.com/search.html?q=pixel)

Answer (score 1):

How about the X11 Fixed font? It comes standard with Ubuntu and is quite readable at 7px.

[image: fixed-font-example]